# Promises .then(async()) versus .then(function(){return async()})

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I'm trying to figure out why the following behavior happens, as well as what the benefit might be. Using bluebird as the promise implementation.

```
printValue = function (value){
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      console.log(value);
      resolve(value)
   });
}

describe.only('promises', function(){
   it('prints values with then', function(done){
      printValue(1)
      .then(printValue(2))
      .then(function(value){
         console.log('then value: ', value);
      })
      .then(done())
   });

   it('prints values with return', function(done){
      printValue(1)
      .then(function(){
         return printValue(2);
      })
      .then(function(value){
         console.log('return value: ', value);
      })
      .then(done())
   });

});
```

output:

```
1
2
then value: 1

1
2
return value: 2
```

why does the first test retain the value from the original promise, when the second test get the value from the second promise? Does this mean that using the `.then(async())` only works when you aren't passing arguments into the functions? or is there still a way to pass arguments using the above the syntax?

Comment: passing a function reference is different than passing a returned value of a function.

Comment: So is passing the function reference only useful when you will not need the resolve value of that reference?

Comment: well, no, they're just "different". use the one that does the thing you need it to do.

Comment: I don't see a reason to downvote. It is a good and well shaped question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not easy to see.

In the first part, you have:

```
printValue(1)
      .then(printValue(2))
      .then(function(value){
         console.log('then value: ', value);
      })
```

You see, you are actually calling `printValue(2)` and it executes immediately when you call it, it doesn't wait for the previous functions to be called and their promises to be resolved. Although `printValue` returns a `Promise`, `.then` expects a function which returns a `Promise` **when called** (or just a function that returns a value).

So in `.then(printValue(2))`, `.then` receives a non-function value, it simply ignores it and goes to the next function in chain.

You can try this for example to see:

```
printValue(1)
    .then("hello!")
    .then(function (val) {
        console.log("got " + val)
    });
```

So, it is really the same as what you have, you just have a function that returns something, here we just replaced it with a value!

You can also try this:

```
var printValue = function (value){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        console.log("called " , value)
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("resolving ", value);
            resolve(value)
        }, value*1000);
    });
}
```

You'll see here:

```
printValue(1)
        .then(printValue(2))
        .then(function (val) {
            console.log("got " + val)
        });
```

Both `printValue(1)` and `printValue(2)` are executed at the same time. After a second, the `printValue(1)` will resolve and `got 1` will be printed.

Answer (score 1):

Hope I can help.
Why does the first test retain the value from the original promise?
- because it's resolved util it finds a function where it can be resolved.
- In order to the promise get resolved it needs to find a proper way to pass the resolved value.
To fix your first scenario you would need to do something like this:

```
printValue(1)
  .then(printValue)      
  .then(function(value){
     console.log('then value: ', value);
  })
```

So when the first printValue(original) gets resolved, it will pass the value to the second printValue.
The way you can pass more arguments is using curry. Take the following example (using *ramda*):

```
'use strict';
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const R = require('ramda');

const printValue = R.curry(function (value){
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      console.log(value);
      resolve(value)
   });
});

const printSum = R.curry(function (val1, val2){
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
       const r = val1 + val2;
      console.log(r);
      resolve(r)
   });
});     

printValue(1)
.then(printSum(R.__)(3))      
.then(function(value){
    console.log('then value: ', value);
})
```

So suppose that you want to sum the result of printValue(original) with another number, using **curry** with Ramda you can specify **R.__** which will take the value of the result of printValue and you can still pass and extra argument in this case *3*.